# I'm trying to install some dependencies, but I ran into an error

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, terminal, raspberry-pi

I typed in "sudo apt-get install -y wiringpi python-pigpio python3-pigpio" but got the error "Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org' "
[Here is a picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbYbu.png)

I set up a fixed address in sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf. I tried looking for solutions online and have tried some of them such as changing the DNS server to 8.8.8.8, but they do not work. Other solutions I have seen I do not understand as I am new to raspberry pi.
Also, I connected it to the internet and it's still connected.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors (and code if any) as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for text, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

to `/etc/resolv.conf`.
Note these are 2 DNS resolvers, which will only be used if your normal DNS (from your ISP) is not responding.  They are provided by Cloudflare and are excellent.
Then try your command again.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried that but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The error says that the DNS server cannot find the hostname `archive.raspberrypi.org`.
If you're using a fixed IP address, make sure that the DNS server is set.
Another option is changing the mirror of the Raspbian repository since the hostname `raspberrypi.org` is not resolvable.
`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
Replace all occurrences of `raspbian.raspberrypi.org` with `mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu`